# Remove Facebook Tag Ids From Album Description when displaying on website

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an Asp.net website and part of the spec is to pull in the photo albums from the clients Facebook Page and display the albums and photos on the website.

This is no problem and is almost finished. I am using a mixtutre of custom code, the C# Facebook SDK and FQL calls to graph.facebook.com

The problem is displaying the album description on the website. It contains Facebook Tag/ID information if another Facebook page has been tagged in the description.

The Tag/Ids are always in the same format @[999184210888:274:TAGGED PAGE NAME]

An example:

```
"Our business learned a lot at the @[244184210470:274:HYPER WEB NET CO] web seminar last week. Here are the photos."
```

To see a real description from graph.facebook.com that contain these Tags/Ids follow this link: https://graph.facebook.com/556781864402615

Has anyone ever encountered this? Is there a standard way to not display these Tags (Maybe by posting a query-string to graph.facebook.com)?

Or a way to extract the name 'HYPER WEB NET CO' from inside the tags?

Or maybe somebody has written some c# and a regex to remove these?

Comment: Has anybody encountered this? Any solutions?

Comment: I've got the exact same issue as this, the regex solution seems to be the most likely but I've no idea about regexs so don't know where to even begin.